# SQL: Get databases by Date and Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of databases that get created during testing that I need to delete automatically after 1 day.

I can select all them as they begin with `TESTDB_`, just not sure how I get the DBs older than 1 day creation date and Delete.

This is as far as I have got. Anyone have any ideas to complete this:

```
 Select name from Sys.Databases where [name] LIKE '%TESTDB_%' and [create_date] <=
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older than one DAY:

```
Declare @dbname varchar(50);
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000);
select @dbname = [name]   from
(Select DATEDIFF(DAY,[create_date],GETDATE()) as diff, [name] from Sys.Databases) as a 
where diff>1 and name like '%TESTDB_%';
SET @cmd = 'Drop Database '  + @dbname;
EXEC(@cmd);
```

Comment: This only work if you are not working on the current DB which is you want to Drop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF() function and compute the difference in HOURS:

```
Select name from Sys.Databases where [name] LIKE '%TESTDB_%' and datediff(hour, [create_date], getdate()) > 24
```